# why is getLastRequest not returning anything?

Tags: php, xml, soap

I am trying to get the XML request:

```
$cgProxy = new SoapClient($WSDL_URL,array('trace' => 1));

try {
        $result = $cgProxy->OrderCreate($cgOrder);

} catch (SoapFault $exc) {
        var_dump($exc);
        echo "Request:\n" . $cgProxy->__getLastRequest(), "\n";
        echo "Response:\n" . $cgProxy->__getLastResponse() . "\n";
}
```

With this I get the soap server error from the $exc dump. But the getLastRequest does not seem to be returning anything. Any thoughts?

I have also tried with htmlspecialchars() and htmlentities() without success . . .

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I also have a situation where I'm sending an array of parameters, and yet the __getLastResponse() shows empty SOAP wrappers with no parameters being passed.

Comment: I had the same problem, nothing was displayed. I found the response in the source code of the page (open it through your browser contextual menu).

Answer (score 31):

`getLastRequest()`:

This method works only if the SoapClient object was created with the trace option set to TRUE.

```
$client = new SoapClient("http://myservice/?WSDL",array("trace"=>1));
```

in this case works for me.

Comment: I have this problem as well and I do have trace enabled so this does not fix the issue.

Comment: Right, the problem existed for me with trace set to true, as I showed in my original post.

Answer (score 11):

Maybe because the XML in your browser doesn't print as string.
If so, try something like this:

```
echo "REQUEST:\n" . htmlentities($client->__getLastRequest()) . "\n";
```

Comment: Didn't help me but def worth checking/being aware of this as a possibility.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is late, but...

Its possible you are never actually making the request. If PHP fails to create the SOAP call, you won't ever get to the point where you are sending the XML request. Check your error log for PHP SOAP errors.